# Strange output of Flyway "info" command with baseline migration

Tags: database, database-migration, flyway

For some reason, the last line is again the entry about baseline, although it is already higher on the list. Is this normal, or can something be done? Everything works fine, but it hurts my eyes a lot.

Maybe I can somehow edit `flyway_schema_history` table, if it helps?

```
Schema version: 6.8.0
+-----------+---------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+--------------------+----------+
| Category  | Version | Description           | Type     | Installed On        | State              | Undoable |
+-----------+---------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+--------------------+----------+
| Versioned | 6.0.0   | Version 6.0.0         | SQL      |                     | Below Baseline     | No       |
| Versioned | 6.0.1   | Version 6.0.1         | SQL      |                     | Below Baseline     | No       |
| Versioned | 6.1.0   | Version 6.1.0         | SQL      |                     | Below Baseline     | No       |
| Versioned | 6.1.1   | Version 6.1.1         | SQL      |                     | Below Baseline     | No       |
| Versioned | 6.2.0   | Version 6.2.0         | SQL      |                     | Below Baseline     | No       |
| Versioned | 6.2.1   | Version 6.2.1         | SQL      |                     | Below Baseline     | No       |
| Versioned | 6.3.0   | Version 6.3.0         | SQL      |                     | Below Baseline     | No       |
|           | 6.4.0   | << Flyway Baseline >> | BASELINE | 2023-01-23 15:39:49 | Baseline           | No       |
| Versioned | 6.4.1   | Version 6.4.1         | SQL      | 2023-01-23 15:40:15 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.4.2   | Version 6.4.2         | SQL      | 2023-01-23 15:40:17 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.5.0   | Version 6.5.0         | SQL      | 2023-01-23 15:40:18 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.6.0   | Version 6.6.0         | SQL      | 2023-01-23 15:40:19 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.6.1   | Version 6.6.1         | SQL      | 2023-01-23 15:40:22 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.6.2   | Version 6.6.2         | SQL      | 2023-01-23 15:40:26 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.6.3   | Version 6.6.3         | SQL      | 2023-01-23 15:40:28 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.6.4   | Version 6.6.4         | SQL      | 2023-01-23 15:40:32 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.7.0   | ************          | SQL      | 2023-05-10 14:49:21 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.7.1   | Version 6.7.1         | SQL      | 2023-05-10 14:49:22 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.7.2   | Version 6.7.2         | SQL      | 2023-05-10 14:49:25 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.8.0   | *******************   | SQL      | 2023-05-10 14:49:28 | Success            | No       |
| Versioned | 6.4.0   | Version 6.4.0         | SQL      |                     | Ignored (Baseline) | No       |
+-----------+---------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

I'm using Gradle plugin. Setup is pretty simple:

```
plugins {
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway").version("9.11.0")
}
flyway {
    locations = arrayOf("classpath:db/migration/v*")
    val dbId = project.extra["db.id"] as? String ?: "db"
    url = project.extra["$dbId.url"] as String
    user = project.extra["$dbId.user"] as String
    password = project.extra["$dbId.password"] as String
}
```

Property values are taken from Gradle properties file.

Comment: Would you be able to share what parameters you are using for your flyway migrations?

Comment: Also, what are you using to run flyway info? is it the Cli or the maven or gradle plugin?

Comment: I'm using Gradle plugin. Setup is pretty simple.